# How to compute sum for each list in Map<>?

Tags: java, functional-programming, hashmap, java-stream, linkedhashmap

This is my map `Map<LocalDate,List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();`

**Question 1:** *How to compute the sum for each list in Map<>*

**Output of the Map<>**

```
2020-01-22 [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 8, 0, 4,0]
2020-01-23 [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4,0] 
2020-01-24 [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5,0]
2020-01-25 [0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4,0]
2020-01-26 [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 8,0]
2020-01-27 [0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4,0]
```

**My try**

```
Map<LocalDate,List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 List<Integer> integerList =map
                .values()
                .stream()
                .map(l->{
                    int sum = l
                            .stream()
                            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                            .sum();
                    return sum;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> The code here that I have tried, I can only form the new list and
> calculate it. But I would like the date and its sum of num display at the same time

**Desired Output (Calculate and display the sum for each list)**

```
2020-01-22 [22]
2020-01-23 [14] 
2020-01-24 [15]
2020-01-25 [14]
2020-01-26 [18]
2020-01-27 [16]
```

Comment: while your calculations are correct, to get the desired output, you should iterate through both the key and the value at the same time, do your math & reassigned the value to the current key.

Comment: is the java stream ```foreach``` applicable in this case to iterate the key and values at the same time?

Comment: not exactly, you iterate the keys instead and then call the `get` method in every iteration.

Comment: okay, so iterate the keys, then for each iteration of keys, use ```get``` to retrieve the integer list for each keys; when get the list, apply my above calculation for the sum of list, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
Map<LocalDate,Integer> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
 result.put(key,value.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`toMap` is a good candidate here:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<LocalDate,List<Integer>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    map.put(LocalDate.of(2020,01,22), List.of(0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 8, 0, 4,0));
    map.put(LocalDate.of(2020,01,23), List.of(0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4,0));
    map.put(LocalDate.of(2020,01,24), List.of(0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 5,0));
    map.put(LocalDate.of(2020,01,25), List.of(0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4,0));
    map.put(LocalDate.of(2020,01,26), List.of(0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 8,0));
    map.put(LocalDate.of(2020,01,27), List.of(0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4,0));

    var output = map.entrySet().stream()
                  .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                 e -> e.getValue().stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum)));

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

One of the overloaded [toMap](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collectors-tomap#:%7E:text=Java%208%20Collectors%20toMap%201%20Overview.%20In%20this,4%20Other%20Map%20Types.%20...%205%20Conclusion.%20) takes a
*keyMapper* - here, it's the key as in original map
and a *valueMapper* - here, we map (get) the value by summing the numbers in list.

The output of above code may look like:

```java
{2020-01-27=16, 2020-01-26=18, 2020-01-25=15, 2020-01-24=15, 2020-01-23=14, 2020-01-22=22}
```

You can use an overloaded `toMap` to instruct to use a `LinkedHashMap`:

```java
var output = map.entrySet().stream()
               .collect(toMap(
                  Map.Entry::getKey, 
                  e -> e.getValue().stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum), 
                  // Conflict resolving function: If the same key is seen again, 
                  // use the latest value. 
                  (oldValue, newValue) -> newValue, 
                  LinkedHashMap::new));

System.out.println(output);
```

The output for above code is:

```java
{2020-01-22=22, 2020-01-23=14, 2020-01-24=15, 2020-01-25=15, 2020-01-26=18, 2020-01-27=16}
```